# for loop in racket doesn't seem to work for me

Tags: loops, for-loop, scheme, racket

I'm absolutely new to Racket. I'm trying to write simple for loop, but DrRacket keeps throwing error "for: this function is not defined".

```
(for ([i '(1 2 3)])
    (display i))
```

Even this simple code (taken from Racket documentation) doesn't work for me. Do I need to declare some libraries or...? I've read the documentation and I have not found any mention about it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

(I'm using the Advanced Student language)

Comment: DrRacket supports several languages. The teaching languages is just a very small subset of the racket language. This choice was made to provide better error messages in the teaching languages (and to avoid the problem of not seeing the tree for the forrest). As @uselpa points out, `for` is not available in the teaching languages. Prefix you program with #lang racket to signal that you want to use the racket language, and then in the lower left corner of DrRacket choose "Determine language from source" as your language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use the racket language:

```
#lang racket
(for ([i '(1 2 3)]) (display i))

Welcome to DrRacket, version 5.2.1 [3m].
Language: racket [custom]; memory limit: 128 MB.
123
>
```